# How to commit & push Magento's vendor directory file in Magento Cloud?

Tags: magento2, magento2-enterprise, magento2.2.8, magento2-cloud

I have made changes in,

> Magento/vendor/magento/module-checkout/Model/PaymentInformationManagement.php

I have made changes in above file, But **how can I commit these changes and PUSH it to Magento cloud** as it will not show in `git diff`.

**Any idea how to push changes of vendor DIR files on Magento Cloud ?**

> Note : I don't want to override in my app directory as it is bug and I
>   want fix it in direct file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Changing file(s) in vendor directly is not a best practice. It's better if you create a patch for the changes, and apply the patch in your Magento Cloud.

To better understanding on how to create and apply patch, see this [link](https://support.magento.com/hc/en-us/articles/360005484154-Create-a-patch-for-a-Magento-2-Composer-installation-from-a-GitHub-commit).

Comment: Thanks for the answer :) 
Is it possible if I want to apply a patch for small amount of time and then remove it from server (Then How can I remove the patch ?)

Comment: It depends on how you apply the patch. For example, if you use `git apply <file.patch>`, you can remove the patch using `git apply -R <file.patch>`

Comment: Use the *m2-hotfixes* folder for your patches: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/cloud/project/project-patch.html

Comment: Hey bro!! @RendyEkoPrastiyo

Comment: @AdityaShah hi, what's up?